# Date in Database Returns in Different Format - Why?

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to understand why my date stored in my SQL database (defined as a `date` column) has the format **MM/dd/yyyy** however when I retrieve it in my java application as a String object it gets formatted as **yyyy-mm-dd**

```
@Column(name="date")
String date;
```

I know I can reformat it manually with the following method

```
Date inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(user.getDate());
String outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(inputDate );
```

But is there any way to prevent the reformatting right off the bat? Would the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation be able to enforce any format I specify? (I've tried this without any luck).

Any input is appreciated, thanks?

Comment: A date is a date it has no format, you probably get the SQL representation when you map it to a string, for example '2016-05-04 07:33:00'

Comment: It's not a very good idea to have the data as `String` in one place and `DATE` in the other. Pick one and then you'll have sensible solutions available.

Answer (score 2):

Date displaying format depends on the tool or IDE which are using to write SQL queries and when we retrieve the date field in java applications it will return `yyyy-MM-dd` format only.

If you want a specific date format you can use database specific methods to format the date value like below:

For MYSQL you can use `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
Ex: select DATE_FORMAT(date_field, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from table_name;
```

refer: [MYSQL DATE FORMATTING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

For MSSQL:

```
Ex: select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_filed, 101) from table_name;
```

refer: [MSSQL DATE FORMATTING](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

For Oracle you can use `TO_CHAR` function.

```
Ex: select TO_CHAR(date_field, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from table_name;
```

refer: [ORACLE DATE FORMATTING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)